# Angular Js Object Filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How can i filter based on object values like 1 or 2 or 3

i am trying to filter my json which looks similar to the names object

This is my code i tried to apply filter but its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names ">
    {{ x.name }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = {
  "1": {
       "name": "some"
  },
  "2": {
       "name": "values"
  },
  "3": {
        "name": "are"
  },
  "4": {
       "name": "there"
  },
  "5": {
        "name": "here"
  }
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you state your goal with this data? Your data structure `$scope.names` is probably not what you want to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter and orderBy do not work on object properties, only arrays. That being said, I think I found a solution that you will like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>
<ul ng-init="nameArray=objArray(names)">
  <li ng-repeat="x in nameArray | filter:searchText">
    {{x.value.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.searchText='';
    $scope.names = {
  "1": {
       "name": "some"
  },
  "2": {
       "name": "values"
  },
  "3": {
        "name": "are"
  },
  "4": {
       "name": "there"
  },
  "5": {
        "name": "here"
  }
    };
$scope.objArray=function (obj) {
    var result=[];
    for (var key in obj) {
        result.push({
            key: key,
            value: obj[key]
        });
    }
    return result;
}


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can filter on property names. I assume these property names are some kind of IDs that you want to filter on. Then your data structure should reflect that and be like this:

```
$scope.names = [
    { id: "1", name: "some" },
    { id: "2", name: "values" },
    { id: "3", name: "are" },
    { id: "4", name: "there" },
    { id: "5", name: "here" }
]
```

Then you can filter like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter: { id: searchId } >
    {{ x.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Replace the `searchId` with your specific scope variable which contains the ID you are looking for.